# map() Function and IE8

Tags: carto

I am using Javisantana example of [Autocomplete](http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/7932459) an everything works inside my map, until I tested my map with IE8 and experienced this error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'map'
```

After some [research](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it seems as if IE does not support that function some of the hacks/patches that I have tried fix that error but seem to cause errors within cartodb js.
Has anyone ran into this problem? If so any tips or advice on a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
 response(data.rows.map(function(r) {
              return {
                label: r.name + "," + r.adm0name,
                value: r.name
              }
            })
          )
```

by

```
var resp = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; ++i) {
  var r = data.rows[i];
  resp.push({
     label: r.name + "," + r.adm0name,
     value: r.name
  });
}
response(r);
```

Optionally you could use underscore.js and do

```
_.map(data.rows, function(r) {
                  return {
                    label: r.name + "," + r.adm0name,
                    value: r.name
                  }
                })
              )
```

Comment: Thank you Javi I ended up using the count with pushing the results to the array. Though I do have one issue of only one result showing up on the drop down. When looking at my net request in firebug its showing all 10 results for that query but yet only displays the last result in the array.